# Define SLO policy which is applied to all cloud run instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-level-agreement

I stumbled upon SLOs for cloud run and find them very useful as it removes the reliance on third parties and the dependencies that come with them. My question is; is it possible to define SLO policies that are applied to all cloud run instances within a project? Similarly how you can define firewalls with tags for VMs?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

- No, you cannot define a single SLO service for all your cloud run instance. You can only create multiple (500) SLOs for a service. Take a look at this documentation: [Creating an SLO](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/slo-monitoring/ui/create-slo)
- Take a look at this documentation: [Use Tags for firewalls](https://cloud.google.com/firewall/docs/use-tags-for-firewalls). You have to:

> 1. Grant Permissions to Tags
> 2. Create the Tag keys and values
> 3. Create a firewall policy rule with Tags
> 4. Bind Tags to VM instances
> 5. Use Tags across peered networks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Thats unfortunate because I like the simplicity of the tags for firewalls. Something similar for SLOs would be nice, especially for standard SLOs